# Iterate over spacy tokens and extract the BILOU tags

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, dataset, spacy

How should I annotate the following sentence with BILOU tags?

I have a function called `get_dataset2` what this function do is it will give the tokens, POS tags and BILOU tags but the things is that am stuck at BILOU tags.

Function:

```html
def get_dataset2(sent):
  head_entity = ""
  candidate_entity = ""

  prv_tok_dep = ""    
  prv_tok_text = ""  

  prefix = ""
  words_ = []
  label_ = []
  tags_ = []

  doc = nlp(sent) 
  
  for tok in doc:
      words_.append(tok.text)
      label_.append(tok.pos_)

      if(tok.text=='JUDGMENT'):
          tags_.append('O')
          next_token1 = doc[tok.i+1]
          #next_tok_loc1 = tok.i+1
          next_token2 = doc[tok.i+2]
          #next_tok_loc2 = tok.i+2

      if(tok.text==next_token1 and (next_token2.pos_=='PUNCT' or next_token2.pos_=='NUM')):
          tags_.append('U-Parties')


      #if(next_token1.pos_=='PROPN' and next_token2.pos_=='PROPN'):
          #tags_.append('U-Parties')

      else:
          tags_.append('O')    

  return (pd.DataFrame({'Token': words_, 'POS': label_,'Tags': tags_}))
```

Problem: `get_dataset2('JUDGMENT Gajendragadkar, J. 1.')` when i pass this sentence to that function then it will successfully extract the tokens and POS but not the BILOU tags.

It should be like :

```html
Tokens         POS       BILOU Tags
JUDGMENT       PROPN     O
Gajendragadkar PROPN     U-Parties
,              PUNCT     O
```

I wan to iterate over tokens like after JUDGMENT I want to identify the second and third token and then I will assign the BILOU tags if it is single then U-parties.

Thanks!

Comment: Havin you considered using a spaCy Matcher instead? It looks like it would be a lot easier. You could use the resulting matches on the spaCy Doc to generate BIO tags. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching